# Implementing solution to IllegalBlockSizeException in Java?

Tags: java, encryption, block

I'm trying to fix my code. In my code, I'm trying to generate a 16bit key which I've already done. Secondly, generate a random message which is also done. Encrypt and decrypt the data which I'm getting errors on. Lastly have a brute force algorithm to decrypt the message which i'll try doing later. So for my encryption the code encrypts it but doesn't encrypt the random generated string. I'm getting bunch of errors.

My Code:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.security.Security;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class Assignment1Demo {

private static String msg;

private static String msgE;

private static String msgD;

private static int key;


public static void main(String[] args){

//TODO: You can only call methods in main method

key = generateKey();

msg = generateMsg();

msgE = encryption(key,msg);

bruteForce(msgE);

}

private static int generateKey() {

//TODO: implement step a (randomly generate 16-bit key)

//16 bit digit means 2^16 -1 in decimal

Random rand = new Random();

return rand.nextInt((int) (Math.pow(2, 16)-1));

}

private static String generateMsg() {

//TODO: implement step b (randonly generate a string with an even number of characters)
    String chractersU="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    String chractersL=chractersU.toLowerCase();
    String space=" ";
    String alphanum=chractersU+space+chractersL;
    String random="";
    int length=alphanum.length();
    Random rand=new Random();
    char[] text=new char[length];

    for(int i=0;i<length;i++) {
        text[i]=alphanum.charAt(rand.nextInt(alphanum.length()));
    }


for(int i=0;i<text.length/2;i++) {
    if(text.length%2!=0) {
        random += text[i];
    }}


return random;

}

private static String encryption (int key, String msg) {

//TODO: implement step c (encrypt the message)

String strData="";
String strKey=Integer.toString(key);

    try {
        SecretKeySpec skeyspec=new SecretKeySpec(strKey.getBytes(),"Blowfish");
        Cipher cipher=Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeyspec);
        byte[] encrypted=cipher.doFinal(msg.getBytes());
        strData=new String(encrypted);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    return strData;
}






private static void decryption(int key, String msgE) {

//TODO: implement step d (decryption)

String strKey = Integer.toString(key);
String strData="";

try {
    SecretKeySpec skeyspec=new SecretKeySpec(strKey.getBytes(),"Blowfish");
    Cipher cipher=Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeyspec);
    byte[] decrypted=cipher.doFinal(msgE.getBytes());
    strData=new String(decrypted);

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();

}
System.out.println(strData);
}

private static void bruteForce(String msgE) {

//TODO: implement bruteForce algorithm, you may need the above decryption(key,msgE) method

boolean isEnglisString = msgE.matches("[a-zA-Z]+");

if(isEnglisString)

System.out.println("Yes encrypted message is Randomly English generated message " + msgE);

else
System.out.println("encrypted message is Not Randomly english generated message "+msgE);
decryption(key, msgE);
isEnglisString = msgD.matches("[a-zA-Z]+");
if(isEnglisString)
System.out.println("Yes decrypted message is Randomly english generated message "+ msgD);
else
System.out.println("decrypted message is not Randomly english generated message "+ msgD);
}}
```

Errors:

```
javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 8 when decrypting with padded cipher
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:936)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:847)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.BlowfishCipher.engineDoFinal(BlowfishCipher.java:319)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2189)
    at Assignment1Demo.decryption(Assignment1Demo.java:110)
    at Assignment1Demo.bruteForce(Assignment1Demo.java:132)
    at Assignment1Demo.main(Assignment1Demo.java:30)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Assignment1Demo.bruteForce(Assignment1Demo.java:133)
    at Assignment1Demo.main(Assignment1Demo.java:30)
```

Comment: The error message seems pretty straight forward, The input length has to be a multiple of 8 but isn't. To fit it you have to workout why, and correct it.

Comment: How would I fix that. The string is randomly generated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your string is randomly generated, but when the block size does not match what the cipher expects, you need to apply an acceptable padding algorithm, so the size of your input is aligned with algorithm. This is applicable to all block ciphers.

This example is a simple meter for a cipher, not that one could use something like as algorithm
"AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"
"RC2/CBC/PKCS5Padding"
"DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding
(PKCS#5 padding is defined for 8-byte block sizes)

```
@Override
    public SimpleMeter testEncryption(File baseInput, String algorithm, String provider) throws NoSuchProviderException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {
        Cipher cipherEncryption;

        SimpleMeter meter = new SimpleMeter();

        SecureRandom randGenerator = new SecureRandom();
        KeyGenerator generator;

        generator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(algorithm.split("/")[0], provider);
        generator.init(randGenerator);
        SecretKey key = generator.generateKey();

        cipherEncryption = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm, provider);
        cipherEncryption.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

        try (BufferedInputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(baseInput))) {

            CipherInputStream encryptionStream = new CipherInputStream(input, cipherEncryption);

            meter.start();

            while (encryptionStream.read() > -1);

            encryptionStream.close();//End all encryption and decryption operation

            meter.stop();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            meter = null;
        }

        return meter;
    }
```

Another example without the streams:

```
cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encryptedString.getBytes(CHARSET_ISO_8859_1));
 decryptedString = new String(decrypted, CHARSET_ISO_8859_1);
```

It is really not necessary, but if you wanna go with the base64, you can look for Apache:
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/

---

Examples using your code

1) ECB mode

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.util.Random;

public class Assignment1Demo {

    private static String msg;

    private static byte[] msgE;

    private static String msgD;

    private static int key;

    public static void main( String[] args ) {

        //TODO: You can only call methods in main method

        key = generateKey( );

        msg = generateMsg( );

        msgE = encryption( key, msg );

        bruteForce( msgE );

    }

    private static int generateKey( ) {

        //TODO: implement step a (randomly generate 16-bit key)

        //16 bit digit means 2^16 -1 in decimal

        Random rand = new Random( );

        return rand.nextInt( ( int ) ( Math.pow( 2, 16 ) - 1 ) );

    }

    private static String generateMsg( ) {

        //TODO: implement step b (randonly generate a string with an even number of characters)
        String chractersU = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        String chractersL = chractersU.toLowerCase( );
        String space = " ";
        String alphanum = chractersU + space + chractersL;
        String random = "";
        int length = alphanum.length( );
        Random rand = new Random( );
        char[] text = new char[ length ];

        for ( int i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
            text[ i ] = alphanum.charAt( rand.nextInt( alphanum.length( ) ) );
        }

        for ( int i = 0; i < text.length / 2; i++ ) {
            if ( text.length % 2 != 0 ) {
                random += text[ i ];
            }
        }

        return random;

    }

    private static byte[] encryption( int key, String msg ) {

        //TODO: implement step c (encrypt the message)

        byte[] encrypted =new byte[]{};
        String strKey = Integer.toString( key );

        try {
            SecretKeySpec skeyspec = new SecretKeySpec( strKey.getBytes( ), "Blowfish" );
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init( Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeyspec );
            encrypted = cipher.doFinal( msg.getBytes( ) );

        }
        catch ( Exception e ) {
            e.printStackTrace( );

        }
        return encrypted;
    }

    private static void bruteForce( byte[] msgE ) {

        //TODO: implement bruteForce algorithm, you may need the above decryption(key,msgE) method


        decryption( key, msgE );
    }

    private static void decryption( int key, byte[] msgE ) {

        //TODO: implement step d (decryption)

        String strKey = Integer.toString( key );
        String strData = "";

        try {
            SecretKeySpec skeyspec = new SecretKeySpec( strKey.getBytes( ), "Blowfish" );
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init( Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeyspec );
            byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal( msgE);
            strData = new String( decrypted );

        }
        catch ( Exception e ) {
            e.printStackTrace( );

        }
        System.out.println( strData );
    }
}
```

---

Example 2) your code with CBC mode

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.security.AlgorithmParameters;
import java.util.Random;

public class Assignment1Demo {

    private static String msg;

    private static byte[] msgE;

    private static String msgD;

    private static int key;
    private static byte[] encodedParams;

    public static void main( String[] args ) {

        //TODO: You can only call methods in main method

        key = generateKey( );

        msg = generateMsg( );

        msgE = encryption( key, msg );

        bruteForce( msgE );

    }

    private static int generateKey( ) {

        //TODO: implement step a (randomly generate 16-bit key)

        //16 bit digit means 2^16 -1 in decimal

        Random rand = new Random( );

        return rand.nextInt( ( int ) ( Math.pow( 2, 16 ) - 1 ) );

    }

    private static String generateMsg( ) {

        //TODO: implement step b (randonly generate a string with an even number of characters)
        String chractersU = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        String chractersL = chractersU.toLowerCase( );
        String space = " ";
        String alphanum = chractersU + space + chractersL;
        String random = "";
        int length = alphanum.length( );
        Random rand = new Random( );
        char[] text = new char[ length ];

        for ( int i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
            text[ i ] = alphanum.charAt( rand.nextInt( alphanum.length( ) ) );
        }

        for ( int i = 0; i < text.length / 2; i++ ) {
            if ( text.length % 2 != 0 ) {
                random += text[ i ];
            }
        }

        return random;

    }

    private static byte[] encryption( int key, String msg ) {

        //TODO: implement step c (encrypt the message)

        byte[] encrypted =new byte[]{};
        String strKey = Integer.toString( key );

        try {
            SecretKeySpec skeyspec = new SecretKeySpec( strKey.getBytes( ), "Blowfish" );
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init( Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeyspec );
            encrypted = cipher.doFinal( msg.getBytes( ) );
            encodedParams = cipher.getParameters().getEncoded();
        }
        catch ( Exception e ) {
            e.printStackTrace( );

        }
        return encrypted;
    }

    private static void bruteForce( byte[] msgE ) {

        //TODO: implement bruteForce algorithm, you may need the above decryption(key,msgE) method


        decryption( key, msgE );
    }

    private static void decryption( int key, byte[] msgE ) {

        //TODO: implement step d (decryption)

        String strKey = Integer.toString( key );
        String strData = "";

        try {
            SecretKeySpec skeyspec = new SecretKeySpec( strKey.getBytes( ), "Blowfish" );
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            AlgorithmParameters params = AlgorithmParameters.getInstance("Blowfish");
            params.init(encodedParams);
            cipher.init( Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeyspec, params );
            byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal( msgE);
            strData = new String( decrypted );

        }
        catch ( Exception e ) {
            e.printStackTrace( );

        }
        System.out.println( strData );
    }
}
```

Comment: Note how the string is being generated in the `generateMsg` method - the length is actually constant (and quite funny).

Comment: How would I apply that. would that be a seperate method or would I just need to fix my random string.

Comment: nono, your code should work, no matter what is you input - in this case the generated on. But you need to select a padding algorithm for when the size do not align with the block size.

Comment: How would you implement a padding algorithm. I'm sorry i'm new to Java. Would it be something simple as adding one extra line.

Comment: https://github.com/victorlima02/Crypto/blob/fb4cf2db41a58c5180354638ae01a042c493ad48/src/crypto/ciphers/block/feistel/FeistelCipher.java

Comment: please note that this example is just an example, it is not meant to be used in production. there are standards for that, just like there are standards for ciphers.

Comment: So pretty much I have to have whole new method based on that. Could you show me how to implement it on my code.

Comment: one standard is PKCS5Padding, I am looking here for an example. I built a benchmark for this once.

Comment: @fafa as encryption algorithm you may provide mode of operation and padding, e. g. `Blowfish/CBC/PKCS5Padding`.  You may be as well interested in some [working examples](https://gusto77.wordpress.com/2017/10/30/encryption-reference-project/)

Comment: exactly! I am posting an example

Comment: btw: PKCS#5 padding is defined for 8-byte block sizes

Comment: Cipher cipher=Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish"); -> Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish/ECB/PKCS5Padding");

Comment: @Victor do not use ECB and unless you really have to. Choose any other mode of operation (cbc, ofb, crt,..), proper IV and authenticated encryption.

Comment: Not recommended at all, just example from several in the answer

Comment: the last two examples is using your code, I tried not to change much so you can see where you got wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In short, you are using encrypted binary data and assuming it is valid text, which generally speaking it won't be.

You can encode a String as a byte[] using UTF-8 encoding, but not all possible byte[] encoding are valid Strings. When you encrypt data, any possible byte could be used, but this cannot always be turned into a String using standard character encoding.  This can result in the length of data changing which is why it is no longer a multiple of 8 as it was when the data was encoded.

A simple way to encode data as a printable string is to use Base64 encoding.

In `encryption` use

```
        strData = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(encrypted);
```

and in `decryption` use

```
        byte[] decrypted=cipher.doFinal(DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(msgE));
```

This way you will always be attempting to decrypt the binary data you wrote.

Another option is to not try to store binary data in a String, and just use the original `byte[]`

---

EDIT can you try this, using `byte[]` instead of a `String`

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class A {
    public static void main(String... args) {

        String text = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
            byte[] encrypt = encryption(1, text.substring(0, i));
            String hello = decryption(1, encrypt);
            System.out.println(hello);
        }
    }

    private static byte[] encryption(int key, String msg) {
        String strKey = Integer.toString(key);
        try {
            SecretKeySpec skeyspec = new SecretKeySpec(strKey.getBytes(), "Blowfish");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeyspec);
            return cipher.doFinal(msg.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }


    private static String decryption(int key, byte[] msgE) {
        String strKey = Integer.toString(key);
        try {
            SecretKeySpec skeyspec = new SecretKeySpec(strKey.getBytes(), "Blowfish");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeyspec);
            byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(msgE);
            return new String(decrypted, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @fafa you need to import it with `import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
` at the start or get your IDE to add this automatically.

Comment: I'm trying this now but i'm getting the same thing it's not resovled.

Comment: @fafa can you try the example I have added?

Comment: I'm getting this error: The method printBase64Binary(byte[]) is undefined for the type DatatypeConverter

Comment: So the iimport javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter; on my eclipse IDE and on intelijay is giving me an unrsolved problem

Comment: @fafa the method has been available since Java 6, which version of Java are you using? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html#parseBase64Binary(java.lang.String)

Comment: The latest one. Java 9 I think I have a mac if that helps

Comment: just Cipher cipher=Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish"); -> Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish/ECB/PKCS5Padding");

Comment: @Victor I didn't need to change this and it's not the reason binary data is being corrupted converting to a String.

Comment: @fafa you can only parse a `String` not a `byte[]`

Comment: So how would I be able to implement that on my code so it works efficiently.

Comment: base64 is not at all the recommended way to do this, and ciphers support padding, there is no need to add dependencies or a lib that is mean for xml. To work efficiently, use the standards like in the other answer.

Comment: @Victor as stated, if the OP doesn't need to convert to a String, I would just use the original `byte[]` in which case padding isn't needed (as my example shows). If the OP need to convert to a String base64 is much better than using the default character encoding.

Comment: So I did that. To fix the datatypeconverter not resolved. I simply made a new class that auto generated stuff but my output now is:

Comment: Yes encrypted message is Randomly English generated message null
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Null input buffer
 at Assignment1Demo.decryption(Assignment1Demo.java:121)
 at Assignment1Demo.bruteForce(Assignment1Demo.java:136)
 at Assignment1Demo.main(Assignment1Demo.java:35)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Null input buffer
 at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2185)
 at Assignment1Demo.decryption(Assignment1Demo.java:117)
 ... 2 more

Comment: So Peter if you could make it run with just byte and without string. How would you implement that. I'm just trying to have this code work and preferably not get any error.s

Comment: @fafa the class you added returns a `null` instead of converting the `byte[]`. Just using the class which is in the JVM. In Java 9 which might be an optional library but in Java 6-8 it's standard.

Comment: @fafa I have changed the example to use a `byte[]` which is better IMHO anyway.

Comment: I made examples from your code, using ECB and CBC modes (do not use ECB one in production ). keep to standards, and avoid adding dependencies that were not meant for crypto. PKCS5 and PKCS7..are just there waiting for you to request them.